# How to alter names within table column in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, renaming

I have two tables, one is a Master data table with the column 'sampleID' with names such as '1 2 3 4...'

the other table is a Results table with the column 'samples' with names such as 'W1 W2 W3 W4...'

I would like to add the Results into my Master table, but first I believe I must make sure they are named the same way. Therefore I am looking for a way to rename the Results.samples column from 'W1' to '1' such as is in the Master table.

Something like this:

```
Results.samples = Results.samples(-'W')
```

If only it would be that easy...

Comment: See: [Modify Units, Descriptions and Table Variable Names](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/modify-units-descriptions-and-table-variable-names.html). Column names must be [valid variable names](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/variable-names.html), which cannot start with a number.

Answer (score 1):

```
%Taking some sample data
sampleID = [38;43;38;40;49];
MasterTable = table(sampleID,'RowNames',{'1','2','3','4','5'});
samples = [71;69;64;67;64];
ResultTable = table(samples,'RowNames',{'W1','W2','W3','W4','W5'});
```

which gives this:

```
T1 = 

         sampleID
         ________

    1    38      
    2    43      
    3    38      
    4    40      
    5    49      


T2 = 

          samples
          _______

    W1    71     
    W2    69     
    W3    64     
    W4    67     
    W5    64
```

Now making the adjustments:

```
ResultTable.Properties.RowNames = MasterTable.Properties.RowNames ;
Combined =[MasterTable ResultTable]    %Required Result
```

**Output:**

```
Combined = 

         sampleID    samples
         ________    _______

    1    38          71     
    2    43          69     
    3    38          64     
    4    40          67     
    5    49          64
```